# eclipse neno installer install multi versions

Tags: eclipse

I intalled "eclipse-javase neno" and "eclipse-php neno" with "eclipse installer",and then installed pydev plugin in "eclipse-javase", but when I opened "eclipse-php" ,in the "perspective" "pydev" also showed up ,but error occured when clicking on it.I am wondering if it is possible to seprate the two eclipse versions from influencing each other.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **each installation with its own workspace**, because the window layout (including the perspective switch buttons at the top right which are displayed once a perspective has been used) is stored in the `.metadata` subfolder of the workspace.

If you want to edit a project with different installations/workspaces, import the project via *Existing Projects into Workspace* without the option *Copy the projects into workspace*.